# Speed up PostGreSQL createdb?

Tags: performance, postgresql

Is there a way to speed up PostgreSQL's createdb command?

Normally I wouldn't care, but doing unit testing in Django creates a database every time, and it takes about 5 seconds.

I'm using openSUSE 11.2 64-bit, PostgreSQL 8.4.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't help you now, but there has been some work done around this in PostgreSQL 9.0.`

What you can try as a workaround is to run with fsync=off. Of course, don't even think about doing this if you have actual data in your database, but if it runs on a test system only, that will make your CREATE DATABASE run a *lot* faster.

Comment: Just tested createdb on Postgres started with "-F" option: less than 0,2s. For unit testing fsync=off should be good.

Answer (score 1):

- If Django [supported postgres schemas](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1051) then you could simply drop the schema in question & recreate it instead of killing the entire database.
- You can still use `DROP OWNED BY ... CASCADE` to drop all objects created by whichever user is configured in Django, bringing the database back to an essentially pristine condition.  See how much faster this is.
- You can shut down Postgres, then untar an existing database cold backup instead of running `initdb`.  See how much faster this is.